# Does uniform continuity on closed disjoint sets hold on their union iff at least one of the sets is compact?

Tags: real-analysis

A function is uniform continuous on A and B, A and B are closed and disjoint, A is compact.

The function is therefore uniform continuous on A∪B. Why is compactness of A necessary?

Comment: Remark: Even though the conclusion *may* be false if none of $A,B$ is compact, it doesn't mean that compactness is necessary (i.e., that $f$ definitely fails to be uniformly continuous whenever $A,B$ are not compact). So there is no "iff" justified

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid xy=0\,\}$ and $B=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid xy=1\,\}$. These are closed subsets of the metric space $\Bbb R^2$ with standard metric.
The function given by $f(x,y)=xy$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and also on $B$ (because it is constant on both), but is not on $A\cup B$ (because $B$ asymptotically touches $A$).